# Installing a Maven project in Eclipse Version: Mars.2 (4.5.2)

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, junit4

I want to install this samples https://github.com/danielolszewski/blog in Eclipse.
I download the repo, unzipped in my workspace dir, run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and from Eclipse Import -> Existing Maven Projects ->

Everything seems to be OK, but Eclipse does not recognize the Junit classes.
Instead of see Run As -> `Junit Test` , I see `Run As -> Configurations`

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you don't use the right view. Does it work when using the View "Project Explorer"? It should be available as tab. If not you can add it using menu "Window > Show View".

Comment: @mm759, please convert to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't use the right view. You have to use the view "Project Explorer"? It should be available as tab. If not you can add it using menu "Window > Show View".